# Using FactoryGirl without Rails, ActiveRecord or any database with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I was wondering if anyone knows whether it's possible to use FactoryGirl without any of the aforementioned prerequisites.

I would like to use it to generate on-the-fly test data when driving UI automation tests for both mobile and web, and even possibly API.

I know I could create some custom helper classes/methods and use getters and setters, etc., but I thought it would be good to use this awesome little gem.

I have searched quite extensively and also tried to set up a basic RSpec project (I also tried Cucumber), but to no avail. It still appears that I need classes to be instantiated with the relevant login in order to consume it.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user  do
    firstname { Faker::Name.first_name }
    lastname { Faker::Name.last_name }
    age { 1 + rand(100) }
  end
end
```

Then if I try to call it in a RSpec file...

```
describe...
  it...
    user = build_stubbed(:user)
  end
end
```

I have also read the docs and tried all the other variants, I just keep getting...

```
 Failure/Error: user = build_stubbed(:user)
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant User
```

which suggests I need a class called User with all the logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your surmise is correct -- you still have to write the `User` class yourself. factory_girl works fine with non-ActiveRecord classes, but it doesn't write them for you.

By default factory_girl constructs instances by calling `new` with no parameters, so your class should either not `def initialize` or `initialize` must take no parameters, just like an ActiveRecord model. So the easiest thing to do would be to write `User` like so:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname, :age
end
```

If you decide you need an `initialize` that requires parameters, [you can use factory_girl's `initialize_with` to tell it how to instantiate your class](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction).

Comment: Consider also [using `struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html) like this: `User = Struct.new :firstname, :lastname, :age`. Good explanation [here](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2012-09-01-random-ruby-tricks--struct-new).