# Rails testing non-AR model(class) with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Killmail::Parser
  def initialize(body)
    @body = body
  end
end
```

I also have a factory for it:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :parser, class: Killmail::Parser do
    skip_create

    body '2013.12.02 19:24 bla bla'

    initialize_with { new(attributes) }
  end
end
```

It all works fine as long as I don't try to change default attributes. However when I try to use it like this

```
FactoryGirl.create(:parser, body: 'some different body')
```

It returns this:

```
=> #<Killmail::Parser:0x007fb2ff116548 @body={:body=>"some different body"}>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't really google anything useful on this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343730/using-factorygirl-without-rails-activerecord-or-any-database-with-rspec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling `new(body)` instead of `new(attributes)`? The problem could lie with how you're initializing your Parser class.

`attributes` creates a hash of all the attributes and passes that...

```
initialize_with { new(attributes) }
# roughly translates to
Parser.new({ body: '2013.12.02 19:24 bla bla' })
```

While calling `#new` with just `body` passes just that value as the first param...

```
initialize_with { new(body) }
# roughly translates to
Parser.new('2013.12.02 19:24 bla bla')
```

And you can add as many values to `#new` as you want in the same fashion...

```
# in your FactoryGirl.define
new_var_1 'new_string_1'
new_var_2 2

initialize_with { new(body, new_var_1, new_var_2) }
# roughly translates to
Parser.new('2013.12.02 19:24 bla bla', 'new_string_1', 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the way I should do it! Answer 'new(attributes[:body])' was close one, but now I know I can just 'new(body, and, every, thing, else)'

Comment: Yup! Added that to the answer, you can treat `#new` exactly as you would the actual class initializer, and `#attributes` is just a FactoryGirl helper method for getting a hash of all the values you've set in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, although it's a bit fiddly:

Change

```
initialize_with { new(attributes) }
```

To

```
initialize_with { new(attributes[:body]) }
```

I don't think factory girl was designed for this sort of thing TBH

Comment: Well, this helps, but what if I add more attributes it won't work. :<